# Drop Box style section for my website

Tags: dropbox, collaboration

I have been using dropbox to as a place to distribute files that are too big for email.  We dont do this too often but its becoming more usual.  Does anyone know of a webapp that we can attach to our website that looks a bit more like part of our site that we can use as a file distribution area for the odd zip file or large jpg?

I dont mind paying.

I see dropbox have a paid option but I think its a bit over and above what I need and is pretty costly also.

I would also take a php script that would allow me to do something the same on my own site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you require a "widget" type appearance, but [Windows Live SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com) will offer a free 25GB account and allows you to create public folders. When you want to share a file, you can get a direct link (an odd looking thing) or some code (iframe based I believe) that will display an area to download files.